# Rewrite rule looping indefinitely

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have strange problem with .htaccess I can't solve:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
   RewriteRule watermelonurltest wmelon/core/works.html
</IfModule>
```

When watermelonurltest is accessed, it loops to something like:

```
http://localhost/w/watermelonurltest/index.php/2/index.php/2/index.php/2/index.php/2/index.php/2/index.php/2/index.php/2/(...)
```

Which suggests that `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1` is applied instead of `RewriteRule watermelonurltest wmelon/core/works.html`

I tried to swap these two rules, but then other problems like this one occur.

The problem didn't exist when the first rule was

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

(no question mark after .php)

For some reason, this question mark breaks it.

I can't figure out why this happens and how to fix it - I tried googling a little, but I didn't find anything helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an `index.php` file the directory you're working from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=51C62&print=true

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow I missed it. Here's version after fix: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=11BhYGe0 Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to reproduce this in a fresh setup, but using the **.htaccess** and rules provided, I didn't encounter a loop; the rewrite was to **index.php?/watermelonurltest**; confirmed by looking at the rewrite log.

What redirection does **index.php** do, if any?

Comment: The loop is because (at least I think so) index.php in this case redirects to index.php/2